# Plotting dates only when frequency changes

Tags: python, csv, date, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot date against frequency.
This is how my data set looks like:

```
2017-07-04,13
2018-04-11,13
2017-08-17,13
2017-08-30,13
2018-04-26,12
2018-01-03,12
2017-07-05,11
2017-06-21,11
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(temp)

### Extract data from CSV ###
with open('test.csv', 'r') as n:
    reader = csv.reader(n)
    dates = []
    freq = []
    for row in reader:
        dates.append(row[0])
        freq.append(row[1])

fig = plt.figure()

graph = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot the data as a red line with round markers
graph.plot(dates, freq, 'r-o')
graph.set_xticks(dates)

graph.set_xticklabels(
    [dates]
)

plt.show()
```

This is the result I got:

[image]

The xlabels are very cluttered. I want the dates in the labels to be displayed only when there is a change of value.
I don't know how to do that.
Help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: The dates in your xlabels aren't in chronological order, is that intentional?

Comment: It is not intentional. I did not find a way to sort it properly. I used sorted command but did not work.

Comment: Hi. Please check my edit. I've sorted the dates and made my example more complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would strongly encourage you to use the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library and its [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object to handle your data. It has some very useful functions, such as [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), which will save you some work.

To have matplotlib space the xticks more sensibly, you'll want to convert your dates to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects (instead of storing your dates as strings).

Here I'll read your data in with pandas, parse the dates and order by date:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/test.csv', names=['date', 'freq'], parse_dates=['date'])
# Sort by date
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
```

You can then go ahead and plot the data (you'll need the latest version of pandas to automatically handle the dates):

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Plot date against frequency
ax.plot(df['date'], df['freq'], 'r-o')

# Rotate the tick labels
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

fig.tight_layout()
```

If you *only* wanted to display dates when the frequency changes, the following would work

```
ax.set_xticks(df.loc[np.diff(df['freq']) != 0, 'date'])
```

though I wouldn't recommend it (the unequal spacing looks messy)

Comment: Glad you mentioned rotating the labels, I think that's a good option when plotting data like this.

Comment: I tried your fix but I got a Typeerror.  a = op(a[slice1], a[slice2])
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U2') dtype('<U2') dtype('<U2')